# Add tag "bug", to ask for software bugs

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

I propose to add the tag `bug`.

For example, I had a question whether certain open source code has a bug.

Comment: The tag [bug] and [bugs] have already been burinated and blacklisted I think. There is however [debugging] and various related tags; relevant https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121184/kill-the-bugs-tag

Comment: If you know it is a bug, how does that help you?

Comment: @fbueckert I am suspecting a bug and ask whether it is really a bug

Comment: And how does that help you solve your problem?  Does a yes or no do anything to stop blocking you?

Comment: If it is a bug, I will report it to the bug tracker

Comment: Please read the [tag guidance for the Feature-request tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/info): "Your question should contain the details of your proposal, including a justification of why the new feature is needed and/or how it can improve the community. Basically, prove to the administration that they should spend time developing your feature." Just a vague description of the feature is **not** a real justification.

Comment: Btw, a good tag is a unit of programming someone could become an expert at (like numpy, CloudSQL, or linear interpolation, say). Who could ever be a 'bug' expert?

Comment: @Patrice I do consider [George McGavin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_McGavin) a bug expert. I don't think he's on Stack Overflow, though.

Comment: I don't think asking if something is a bug by itself is on-topic. To me, it sounds similar to asking if something's possible.

Answer (score 12):

Depends on your usage of said open-source code.  That's not to say that there aren't bugs in open source at all or that people haven't posted about it - *quite* the opposite - but tagging the question as [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) doesn't convey anything besides one of these two things:

- The code I have has a bug in it.
- The code I'm using has a bug in it.

...and I'm certain that there will be plenty of people using the former definition as opposed to the latter.

I'd say we don't need this bug.  Surely if the library exists and has a tag on Stack Overflow, use *that* tag instead to convey what you're talking about.  Including code which exhibits the alleged bug would go a long way to making your question better.